# Адрес в регистрах ds и es

Tags: ассемблер

У меня есть такой код загрузчика ОС:

```
BITS 16

org 7C00h

jmp short bootloader_start  ; Jump past disk description section
nop     

;---- skip code

bootloader_start:
    cli         ; Disable interrupts while changing stack
    xor AX,AX
    mov SS,AX       ;Work in stack just below this routine
    mov SP,7C00h
    sti         ; Restore interrupts

    xor AX,AX
    mov     es, ax

    push    ES
    pop DS      ; DS = ES = code = 0.
```

Мне не понятен коментарий DS = ES = code = 0 в последней строке кода. Имеется в виду что DS и ES равно 0 и этот 0 это начало всей памяти компьютера, или этот 0 обозначает нулевое смещение от начала кода т.е. смещение от 7c00h? Как может быть code = 0? Если code == 7c00h.

Answer (score 1):

> Как может быть code = 0? Если code == 7c00h.

Нет, значение регистра `CS` (как и других сегментных регистров) здесь действительно устанавливается в `0`. А значение `7C00h`, которое задаётся меткой `ORG` - это смещение внутри сегмента `CS`. То есть код будет загружен в ОЗУ по адресу `0000h:7C00h` (или - абсолютному адресу `7C00h`).